# Breaking out of If-Then when a certain requirement is met in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am given the assignment of coding a hailstone sequence in Haskell. I must be given an integer and create a list of integers ending with the last number 1, eg.

```
-- > hailstone 4
-- [4,2,1]
-- > hailstone 6
-- [6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]
-- > hailstone 7
-- [7,22,11,34,17,52,26,13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]
```

My answer should have just one 1 at the end, however I do not know how to break out of the loop once reaching 1.

```
hailstone :: Integer -> [Integer]
hailstone = takeWhile (>=1) . (iterate collatz)
  where collatz n = if n == 1
                    then 1
                    else if even n 
                    then n `div` 2 
                    else 3*n+1
```

I end up with infinite 1's at the end of this. How can I fix this?

Comment: Not using `iterate` would be one solution.  Iterate implies an infinite list after all.

Comment: Notice that your condition `(>=1)` is satisfied even for `1`. That explains your infinite ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like [**`takeUntil :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.14/docs/Data-List-HT.html#v:takeUntil) from the [**`utility-ht`** package [hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht). This function will:

> Take all elements until one matches. **The matching element is returned, too**. This is the key difference to `takeWhile (not . p)`. It holds `takeUntil p xs == fst (breakAfter p xs)`.

So we can use that to include the `1`:

```
import Data.List.HT(takeUntil)

hailstone :: Integer -> [Integer]
hailstone = takeUntil (== 1) . iterate collatz
  where collatz 1 = 1
        collatz n | even n = div n 2
                  | otherwise = 3 * n + 1
```

or we can implment `takeUntil` ourself:

```
takeUntil :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeUntil p = go
    where go [] = []
          go (x:xs) | p x = [x]
                    | otherwise = x : go xs
```

or with a fold:

```
takeUntil :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeUntil p = foldr (\x y -> x : if p x then [] else y) []
```

For negative numbers, the `collatz` can get stuck in an infinite loop:

```
Prelude> hailstone (-7)
[-7,-20,-10,-5,-14,-7,-20,-10,-5,-14,-7,-20,-10,-5,-14,-7,-20,-10,-5,-14,
```

We thus might want to change the condition for all numbers less than or equal to `1`:

```
hailstone :: Integer -> [Integer]
hailstone = takeUntil (<= 1) . iterate collatz
  where collatz 1 = 1
        collatz n | even n = div n 2
                  | otherwise = 3 * n + 1
```

Comment: `takeUntil` is `takeWhile . fmap not`, right? i.e., wouldn't `takeWhile (/= 1)` work instead?'

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: no, the idea of `takeUntil` is that it includes the matching element as well.

Comment: OTOH, if it terminates then it must terminate with a 1 so we can simply append a 1 to whatever the result list is.

Comment: (Under the assumption that `[1..] ++ [1]` is operationally equivalent to `[1..]`.)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: yes indeed. The `takeUntil` is more useful if we want to make more sophisticated :)

Answer (score 2):

All this use of `takeUntil`, `iterate`, *breaking out* has a very imperative feel for me (*do* something with the numbers until you reach 1 - and then how the hell do I stop? what is the Haskell equivalent of a `break` statement.....?)

There is nothing wrong with that, and it wil work eventually, but when using Haskell, is often better to think a bit more declaratively: the tail of a hailstone sequence (other than `[1]`) is another (shorter) hailstone sequence, so `hailstone n = n : hailstone (f n)` for some `f`

Thus:

```
hailstone n
   | n == 1    = [1]
   | even n    = n : hailstone (n `div` 2)
   | otherwise = n : hailstone (3*n + 1)
```

Comment: Though nobody has called me out on this: by saying that the tail of a hailstone sequence is  always a _shorter_ sequence, I implied that all hailstone sequences must be finite (which they are, of course, although a comment field is not large enough to contain my brilliant proof :-)

Answer (score 1):

The sole *classic* library function that seems to offer some hope is [unfoldr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr). It uses the Maybe monad, and returning `Nothing` is what stops the recursion.

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

You have to pick the proper function argument:

```
import Data.List

hailstone :: Integer -> [Integer]

hailstone n = 
    let  next nn = if (even nn) then (div nn 2) else (3*nn+1)
         unfn nn = if (nn==1) then Nothing else let nx = next nn in Just (nx,nx)
    in
         n : (unfoldr unfn n)

main = do
    putStrLn $ "hailstone 7 is: " ++ show (hailstone 7)
```

That way, the stopping criterion is clearly separated from the successor function.